# Can I check if std::optional function-parameter contains a value at compile-time?

Tags: c++, c++17

cppreference.com states that [static_assert needs to be supplied a `constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) value of type `bool`. And that the method [`std::optional::operator bool()` is declared `constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool).

This actually is about `std::optional` as function parameter. Imagine the following:

```
class T {
public:
    virtual void f(std::optional<int> i) {...};
};
class U : public T {
public:
    virtual void f(std::optional<int> i) override {
        static_assert(i, "This is no longer optional");
        f(i.value());
    }
    virtual void f(int i) {...}
};
```

The parameter that was optional in the base class transformed to a required parameter.
It is perfectly clear to me that this form of problem originates in bad OO-design, but I can't be asked to refactor it just now. I'll do that some point later (I promise :D). But I'd like to insert a quick compiler check.

My compiler tells me that:

> [There is a] non-constant condition for static assertion

Why is this considered non-const?

Comment: provide some example it will be easier to discuss.

Comment: "*I assume not.*" There's no need to assume things when you have clearly explained why they should work. And when it's *trivial* to check to see if they work.

Comment: I edited the question. I left the important part out... Sorry about that.

Comment: @MartinB.: That's a *completely different question* now!

Answer (score 1):

First, parameters to functions, even parameters to `constexpr` functions, are *never* `constexpr`. You can only pass a `constexpr` value via a template parameter.

So this has nothing to do with `optional`.

Second, even if functions were allowed to take `constexpr` parameters, `virtual` functions would certainly *not* be able to do so. They rely on dynamic, runtime dispatch, so compile-time checking within the function is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **really** simple answer: `i` is not `constexpr` because `i` is a function argument (which is never `constexpr` unless in a **compile-time call** for a `constexpr` function, which is not the case.